# Regex for below mention string in c#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

```
S12345>T12345:abcdancd
```

Here start with `S` & few numeric char then `>` then `T` & few numeric char then `:` and any string.

Comment: _Here start with_ what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@"^S\d+>T\d+:[a-z]+",Regexoption.Ignorecase

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you can also use simpler means like [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string str = "S12345>T12345:abcdancd";

string[] parts = str.Split('>', ':');

foreach (var part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Output:

```
// S12345
// T12345
// abcdancd
```